# ClassNotFoundException loading runtime compiled subclass

Tags: java, java-compiler-api, urlclassloader

I am using JavaCompiler to compile CustomProcessor.java from within a web application at runtime

```
package com.notmycompany;

import com.mycompany.Processor;
import com.mycompany.Event;

public class CustomProcessor extends Processor {

    @Override
    public void process( Event evt) {
        // Do you own stuff
        System.out.println( "My Own Stuff");
    }
}
```

Compilation goes well, I end up with a class file that I am trying to load using `URLClassLoader`

```
URL[] urls = new URL[]{ new URL("file://d:/temp/") }; 
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class clazz = ucl.loadClass("com.notmycompany.CustomProcessor");
```

The problem is I am hitting a `ClassNotFoundException` on `Processor` which I am using elsewhere in the application (as in I known it's there).
**What do I need to do so `com.mycompany.Processor` is visible** at runtime?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.Processor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 30 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the location of `CustomProcessor.class`?

Comment: `d:/temp/com/notmycompany/`

Comment: Does URLClassLoader need the path to all other classes?

Comment: I believe MonoThreaded is correct, in your urls include the jar file / directory which contains the Processor class and it should work

Comment: Well it did help. I now get an `InstanciationException` ... getting there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of using a `URLClassLoader` fed with a complete classpath
As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517275/reflection-type-mismatch) I used

```
URLClassLoader ucl2 = new URLClassLoader( new URL[] { new URL( "file://d:/temp/")}, urlClassLoader);
Class<?> clazz = ucl2.loadClass("com.notmycompany.CustomProcessor");
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem - my code worked fine until running it from a web application.

It turned out I was using the wrong parent class loader as in the linked question, i.e., I changed:

    URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader (url , (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

to

    URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader (url , Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());