# Reflection type mismatch

Tags: java, reflection, getconstructor

I have compiled a class at runtime which I would like to use on the fly, provided that its constructor takes one parameter

```
package com.notmycompany;

import com.mycompany.Manager;
import com.mycompany.Processor;

import com.mycompany.Event;

public class CustomProcessor extends Processor {


    public CustomProcessor( Manager m) {
        super( m);
    }

    @Override
    public void process( Event evt) {
        // Do you own stuff
        System.out.println( "My Own Stuff");
    }
}
```

Compilation goes fine and I can load the class right away. But the constructor is giving me a hard time.

```
Class<?> clazz = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.notmycompany.CustomProcessor");
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor( com.mycompany.Manager.class);
this.customProcessor = (Processor) constructor.newInstance( this.manager);
```

In this case, `getConstructor` throws a `NoSuchMethodException`

I tried using `getConstructors` instead, which only gets me one step further with `IllegalArgumentException` during `newInstance` call (of course this.manager is com.mycompany.Manager)

```
Constructor<?> list[] = clazz.getConstructors();
Constructor<?> constructor = list[0];
this.customProcessor = (Processor) constructor.newInstance( this.manager);
```

Watever I do, there is a mismatch between Manager object at runtime and compilation
**How can I fix this constructor signature?**
**Edit 1:** getParameterTypes output

```
        for( Class<?> c : constructor.getParameterTypes()) {
            System.out.println( c);
        }
```

outputs

```
class com.mycompany.Manager
```

**Edit 2:** I removed constructor parameter as a temporary workaround
Now the code throws `ClassCastException` complaining that `com.notmycompany.CustomProcessor cannot be cast to com.mycompany.Processor` when constructor is invoked:

```
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor();
this.customProcessor = (Processor) constructor.newInstance();
```

This all seems to be part of the same problem where runtime classes seem inconsistent with compilation's, although names match.

Comment: What does `clazz.getConstructors()[0].getParameterTypes()` return?

Comment: Added in the edit, looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to get it to work eventually after using a URL that uses the currentThread as parent (as opposed to a URLClassLoader created from scratch with URLs)

```
URLClassLoader ucl = (URLClassLoader)Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URLClassLoader ucl2 = new URLClassLoader( new URL[] { new URL( "file://d:/temp/")},ucl);
Class<?> clazz = ucl2.loadClass("com.notmycompany.CustomProcessor");
```

I hope this can save you 2 days!

Answer (score 1):

Your CustomProcessor class has no constructor because the name of the method you believe to be your constructor is different.

```
public CustomLatencyProcessor(Manager m) {
    super(m);
}
```

Should be changed to

```
public CustomProcessor(Manager m) {
    super(m);
}
```

Because the name of your class is CustomProcessor. Constructor's names must match the name of their containing class exactly.

Comment: Typo fixed, the constructor name was correct in my code and is now correct in the question as well. Once again, this code compiles.